# I am getting a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error while trying to access a page from the browser window?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

this is my controller :-

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @messages = Message.all
  end

  def show
   @messages = Message.all
  end   
end
```

This is new.html.erb :-

```
<%= @messages.name %>, <%= @messages.email %>
```

this is my show.html.erb :-

```
<h1>Inbox</h1>
<table width="500" height="20" border="0" class="borderTable inlineTable" >
  <tr>
    <th>FROM</th>
    <th>SUBJECT</th>
    <th>RECEIVED AT</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @messages.each do |m| %>
 <% if m.to == get_user %> 
   <% if m.have_read == 0 %> 
   <font color="red">   
  <tr>
    <td><font color="blue"><%= link_to m.from, "#" %></font></td>
    <td><font color="blue"><%= link_to m.subject, "#" %></font></td>
    <td><font color="blue"><%= link_to m.created_at, "#" %></font></td>
  </tr>
   <% else %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=link_to m.from , "#"%></td>
    <td><%=link_to m.subject , "#"%></td>
    <td><%=link_to m.created_at, "#" %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %> 
 <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>

<br>
```

I when i try to access the new page by typing in "http://localhost:3000/messages/new" I get the correct page .
But when i try to access "http://localhost:3000/messages/show" I receive an error.

I have made the show.html.erb manually . Am i supposed to specify something in the routes.rb file , for it to work correctly?

this is my routes.rf file :-

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'messages/new'

  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'newmain'  => 'users#newmain'  
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users


end
```

Comment: show the route of the controller..

Comment: So there is no route for the action `show` of the controller `Message`.. can you see it ? :)

Comment: Try to add `resources :messages` to your `config/routes.rb`. This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're supposed to either set `messages` as a resource or specify the route:

Specifying route:

```
get 'messages/show' => 'messages#show'
```

Creating resource:

```
resources :messages
```

I suggest the first one, and I suggest you either always write the `=>` (I do) or never do, as it can become pretty confusing, pretty quickly.